# .modal(dispose) is not a function boostrap 4.3

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, razor

Running into the

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function error

when i try and use `$('#editAppModal').modal('dispose');`

I don't think this is a script reference issue, because I don't get any errors when i open my modal, i only get the error when i click close and try to execute the dispose function.

**Included libraries**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/start/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="~/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/bootstrap-4.3.1.bundle.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

**jQuery dispose code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('rdy');
     $('#editAppModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
         console.log('disposing..');
        $('#editAppModal').modal('dispose');
    })
});
</script>
```

Error happens right at the `modal('dispose')` line.

Comment: How can we run it?? Put it jsfiddle.